# SQL В запросе с использованием функции sum в некоторых местах удвоены итоговые значения

Tags: sql, select, join

Есть вот такая база данных:

[image: Схема базы данных]

**Краткая информация о базе данных "Фирма вторсырья":**

Фирма имеет несколько пунктов приема вторсырья. Каждый пункт получает деньги для их выдачи сдатчикам вторсырья. Сведения о получении денег на пунктах приема записываются в таблицу:
Income_o(point, date, inc)
Первичным ключом является (point, date). При этом в столбец date записывается только дата (без времени), т.е. прием денег (inc) на каждом пункте производится не чаще одного раза в день. Сведения о выдаче денег сдатчикам вторсырья записываются в таблицу:
Outcome_o(point, date, out)
В этой таблице также первичный ключ (point, date) гарантирует отчетность каждого пункта о выданных деньгах (out) не чаще одного раза в день.
В случае, когда приход и расход денег может фиксироваться несколько раз в день, используется другая схема с таблицами, имеющими первичный ключ code:
Income(code, point, date, inc)
Outcome(code, point, date, out)
Здесь также значения столбца date не содержат времени.

**И вот по данной схеме задание:**

В предположении, что приход и расход денег на каждом пункте приема фиксируется произвольное число раз (первичным ключом в таблицах является столбец code), требуется получить таблицу, в которой каждому пункту за каждую дату выполнения операций будет соответствовать одна строка.
Вывод: point, date, суммарный расход пункта за день (out), суммарный приход пункта за день (inc). Отсутствующие значения считать неопределенными (NULL).

**Я попробовала это решить таким методом:**

```
select i.point, i.date, sum(o.out) Outcome, sum(i.inc) Income
from Income i left join Outcome o on i.point = o.point and i.date = o.date
group by i.point, i.date

union

select o.point, o.date, sum(o.out) Outcome, sum(i.inc) Income
from Income i right join Outcome o on i.point = o.point and i.date = o.date
group by o.point, o.date
```

**Но почему-то некоторые итоговые значения удвоены (причем с большинством все в порядке):**
[image: Скриншот результата выполнения запроса]

**Подскажите пожалуйста, почему это происходит, и как это исправить?**
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: При связывании таблиц и расчёте количеств/сумм по полю на стороне "один" просто обязано возникать умножение в соответствии с количеством записей на стороне "много". Решение - группировка и расчёт по одной таблице, и только потом связывание подзапроса с другой таблицей.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо Akina за ответ:

> Решение - группировка и расчёт по одной таблице, и только потом связывание подзапроса с другой таблицей.

```
with i as (
select point, date, sum(inc) as inc
from Income
group by point, date
), o as (
select point, date, sum(out) as out
from Outcome
group by point, date
)

select i.point, i.date, o.out Outcome, i.inc Income
from i left join o on i.point = o.point and i.date = o.date

union

select o.point, o.date, o.out Outcome, i.inc Income
from i right join o on i.point = o.point and i.date = o.date
```

Comment: А точно UNION? Ибо UNION (а точнее, UNION DISTINCT) используется исключительно в случае, когда в суммированном наборе присутствуют полные дубликаты, которые необходимо "схлопнуть". Иначе - используется UNION ALL, который гарантирует не-"схлопывание" случайных дубликатов. И который к тому же не требует дополнительной сортировки.

Comment: Akina, в данном случае имелся в виду именно union, и по смыслу, и при проверке так получается - с union all: Неверно.
* Неверное число записей (больше на 5)

Comment: В данном случае, имхо, лучше бы заменить всю конструкцию left join ... union ... right join на full join. Короче, и, возможно, эффективнее.

Comment: Герман, а тут не получится. Тут ведь left join и right join берут разные поля.

Comment: Или получится?..

Answer (score 0):

```
with i as (
       select point, date, sum(inc) as inc
       from Income
       group by point, date), 
 o as (
       select point, date, sum(out) as out
       from Outcome
       group by point, date)

Select coalesce(i.point,o.point), 
   coalesce(i.date,o.date),
   o.out Outcome,
   i.inc Income
From i Full join o on i.point = o.point and i.date = o.date
```

Comment: С Full Join тоже всё работает

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]